# how can i display company name instead of sup_id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, group-by

I have these three tables:

```
mysql> select * from purchase;
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------+--------+------------+
| purchase_id | list                                      | quantity | sup_id | date       |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------+--------+------------+
|           1 | Hitachi Tv 75 so you can play Cod Warzone |       10 |      2 | 2018-12-20 |
|           2 | Hitachi Domotic System                    |       10 |      2 | 2019-01-15 |
|           3 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 12000 Btu      |        5 |      1 | 2019-04-20 |
|           4 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 1000 Btu       |       10 |      1 | 2019-04-25 |
|           5 | Tool Set Beta Professional                |       20 |      4 | 2019-02-28 |
|           6 | Bridgestone Tyres 4x4                     |        8 |      3 | 2019-01-31 |
|           7 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 3000 Btu       |       10 |      1 | 2019-03-25 |
|           8 | Simple screw 10kg                         |       50 |      4 | 2019-01-30 |
|           9 | Bridgestone Tyres Motorbike 180/55        |       10 |      3 | 2019-03-21 |
|          10 | Bridgestone Tyres Motorbike 120/60        |       10 |      3 | 2019-03-21 |
|          11 | Hitachi Remote Control                    |        5 |      2 | 2019-06-01 |
|          12 | Tool Set Beta Professional                |        5 |      4 | 2019-03-07 |
|          13 | Halfday peperonata from the balcony       |       10 |      4 | 2019-01-03 |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+----------+--------+------------+
mysql> select * from suppliers;
+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| sup_id | name                      | address                                           | phone     |
+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|      1 | Mitsubishi                | 174-1000, Naka-ku, Yokohama                       | 291-1254  |
|      2 | Hitachi                   | 381-1234, Arakita, Katori-shi, Chiba              | 381-1234  |
|      3 | Bridgestone               | 238-1011, Otomo, Iwaizumi-cho Shimohei-gun, Iwate | 238-1011  |
|      4 | Il paradiso della Brugola | Via Milano                                        | 02-564842 |
+--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------+
mysql> select * from product;
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| prod_id | name                                      | price |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
|       1 | Bridgestone Tyres Motorbike 180/55        |   150 |
|       2 | Bridgestone Tyres Motorbike 120/60        |   120 |
|       3 | Bridgestone Tyres 4x4                     |   300 |
|       4 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 1000 Btu       |   500 |
|       5 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 3000 Btu       |   900 |
|       6 | Mitsubishi Air Conditioner 12000 Btu      |  3000 |
|       7 | Hitachi Remote Control                    |    50 |
|       8 | Hitachi Domotic System                    |   400 |
|       9 | Hitachi Tv 75 so you can play Cod Warzone |  1500 |
|      10 | Tool Set Beta Professional                |   100 |
|      11 | Simple screw 10kg                         |    10 |
|      12 | Halfday peperonata from the balcony       |     5 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
```

I would like to display company for each supplier the total amount of  money spent , and i did this:

```
mysql> SELECT purchase.sup_id,SUM(purchase.quantity*product.price) FROM product JOIN purchase ON product.name = purchase.list GROUP BY purchase.sup_id;
+--------+--------------------------------------+
| sup_id | SUM(purchase.quantity*product.price) |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
|      1 |                                29000 |
|      2 |                                19250 |
|      3 |                                 5100 |
|      4 |                                 3050 |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

Now I would like to display the company name instead of the sup_id.

I tried this but doesnt work:

```
SELECT purchase.sup_id,suppliers.name,SUM(purchase.quantity*product.price) 
FROM product 
JOIN purchase suppliers ON purchase.sup_id = suppliers.sup_id 
GROUP BY purchase.sup_id;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but doesnt work" isn't a precise description of an error or problem. [Edit] the question and elaborate. Do you get an error message? Show it. Is the result not what you want? Show it and describe what's wrong. Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your existing, working query, you just need one more `join` to bring in the `suppliers` table. Then, you can display the supplier `name` in the `select` clause instead of its `sup_id`. Accordingly, you need to add that column in the `group by` clause (it is a good idea to leave column `sup_id` in that clause too, in case two different suppliers have the same name).

Consider:

```
select su.name, sum(pu.quantity * pr.price) total_sales
from product pr
inner join purchase pu on pr.name = pu.list 
inner join suppliers su on su.sup_id = pu.sup_id
group by pu.sup_id, su.name
```

Note the use of of table aliases (`pr`, `pu`, `su`): they make the query shorter and easier to read.